# strlen() function giving segmentation error, how to fix?

Tags: arrays, c, string, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a program that converts strings of text into [leetspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet), as per one of the practice problems for week 2 of Harvard's CS50x. I'm trying to get the length of the string into the function I'm writing to create this convert using strlen, but I keep getting the error "segmentation error (core dumped)."

I've read via other stackoverflow questions that this is a result of not specifiying the NUL character \0 at the end of the string. But given the nature of this program, it's hard to do so, since the argument depends on what the user types at the terminal. I've even tried things like manually adding a \0 after the string I type in the terminal, but that doesn't change anything. How could I fix this?

Here is my code (spoiler for anyone taking the class)

The code so far (spoiler for anyone in CS50)

```
string replace(string word);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./no-vowels word\n");
}
    else
    {
        printf("%s", replace(argv[2]));
    }
}

string replace(string word)
{
    int n = strlen(word); //error here
    char vowel[4] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O'};

    //iterate through each character in string
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      //code
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: for a start you should exit after producing the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `NULL` is stored in `argv[2]` (the element after an element which has the last argument) in your environment when only 1 argument is passed.

The first argument is stored in `argv[1]`, so try `replace(argv[1])` instead of `replace(argv[2])`.

Comment: That worked! So, is it that `argv[0]` refers to the first element -- in this case, the command ./no-vowels -- and `argv[1]` refers to the word written after this?

Comment: @Mailbox Yes, you're right.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to C, so it's easy to forget that if a list has length n,  its last element is in the (n-1)th position, not the nth position.

Answer (score 0):

This is missing an exit

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: ./no-vowels word\n");
        exit(-1); ///  stop running if wrong args
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s", replace(argv[2]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, we haven't been taught exit yet in particular, but we have been taught returning values to check using echo $?. Is this similar to this?

Comment: @Mailbox return (-1) and exit(-1) do the same thing in main. The important point is that you are continueing to execute the rest of the program,  which you should not

Comment: This didn't help the main issue, though. I implemented this, and I still get a segmentation error.

Comment: @Mailbox - yep - I missed the argv[2] error